# jquery on click event; call specific function if available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a solution for my problem.

I need to execute if any rule matches with jquery click, and execute general match.

For example;

I have multiple elements like `a.option`.

So:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.option').click(function(){
        //do something
    });
});
```

But, i have some exceptions like `a.option.model`.

So:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.option.model').click(function(){
        //do this first;
    });

    $('a.option').click(function(){
        //go here after first one in finished!
    });
});
```

I don't want to make statement in general click function...

How can i do this?

Comment: The code you show will do what you seem to be describing. If you bind multiple click handlers to the same element they will be executed in the same order they were bound, so your "do this first"  function will run first...

Comment: I think it will call for both in theory. I did not try... I wonder if any ideas about that.

Comment: It will run both, but it will run them in order. Isn't that what you're asking for? Why don't you actually try it and then come back and ask for more help if you still need it (or delete the question if you don't).

Comment: I'm in a big rush and i really have to make a 12 point shot. So i did not try and ask here while when i'm working for another code block. Thank you for your opinion.

Comment: `I'm in a big hurry` ...would have taken less time to try it than create this question and answer responses. That said, usually eaiser to add a conditional like `if($(this).hasClass('model'))`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
    $(function(){

        $('a.option').click(function(){

          // code called first for both cases goes here

          if($(this).hasClass('model')) {

            // code called only for .model goes here

          }

        });
    });
```